# C#: DataGridView shows only one row

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a problem with a datagridview in C#. I get the data via query from a mysql-database. But for some reason, only the first row from the result is displayed in the gridview. I use the following code to do this stuff:

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, Globals.Connection);
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            object[] dataset = new object[7];
            dataset[0] = reader["sto_name"];
            dataset[1] = reader["esss"];
            dataset[2] = reader["onl_name"];
            dataset[3] = reader["rpc_id"];
            if (reader["datum_aufstellung"].ToString() != "0")
            {
                dataset[4] = getDate(reader["datum_aufstellung"]);
            }
            else
            { 
                dataset[4] = "Kein Datum gesetzt";
            }
            if (reader["datum_abbau"].ToString() != "0")
            {
                dataset[5] = getDate(reader["datum_abbau"]);
            }
            else
            {
                dataset[5] = "Kein Datum gesetzt";
            }
            dataset[6] = reader["id"];
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dataset);
        }
```

It worked, a few lines of code earlier. ^^
Do you have an idea, what the problem is?

**UPDATE:**
The content of the while loop is executed only one time. I was also wondering about that fact, before I asked my question here. But if I execute the Query in an MySQL-Client, it returns more rows than one.

**UPDATE 2:**
I've noticed, that while the whole content of the while-loop is commented, the loop is executed exactly the same times as there are rows in the query-result. Any ideas?

**UPDATE 3:**
It seems that everything after

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dataset);
```

is not executed. Not only in the loop, but in the whole function.
But why?

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**
There was nothing wrong with the code posted here. I had an event in the rest of the code, which executed something, when a row in the dgv is entered. I suppose the loop breaked, when that happened. After removing that event, the dgv was properly filled.

Comment: What's the count of dataGridView1.Rows after your while loop finishes executing?

Comment: I know this might sound obvious but how many rows are you reading from you command? Have you tried putting a breakpoint inside you while() loop to check that it's more than one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `DataAdapter` and use it to populate a DataTable. Create a method for grabbing the data like this :-

```
public DataTable GetDataTable()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection (@"YourCOnnectionString"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand (query, con))
                {
                    var adaptor = new SqlDataAdapter ();
                    adaptor.SelectCommand = cmd;

                    con.Open();
                    adaptor.Fill(dt);

                    return dt;

                }
            }
        }
```

Then You can reference it with your DataGrid :-

```
DataTable Result = GetDataTable();

DatagridView1.DataSource = Result;
```

Comment: I would like to stick to MySql-Classes.

Comment: Then all you need to do is change these commands with the My prefix.

Comment: Okay. Now I get an empty datagridview, though the datatable has the right content.

Comment: Have you figured this problem or is still present? If the DataTable in not a null referenced object then it should work fine.

Comment: "PROBLEM SOLVED: There was nothing wrong with the code posted here. I had an event in the rest of the code, which executed something, when a row in the dgv is entered. I suppose the loop breaked, when that happened. After removing that event, the dgv was properly filled."

Answer (score 1):

Check the RowCount property on the Grid. It maybe set to 1 if so increase it to the desired amount of rows.

Comment: I can't, because of "Update 3". Everything after dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dataset); won't be executed.

Answer (score 0):

There is another easy way.
You can use DataTable instead of dataset and set the dataGridView's DataSource to that DataTable.
It will solve your problem and also using that you can set the column Headers easily.

Comment: But my way should also be able to work. I would like to stick to my way.